# Woocommerce - обновление корзины в попап окне

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

С помощью шорткода вывел корзину во всплывающем окне. Такая своеобразная мини-корзина состряпанная из целой корзины.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы после добавления товара в корзину происходило обновление корзины в попапе. Пытаюсь накинуть тригер следующим образом:

```html
jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
```

Но при выполнении происходит редирект на страницу корзины. А уже на странице корзины если выполнить эту функцию - работает как надо и обновление происходит ajax. Как сделать так, чтобы корзина обновлялась методом ajax и на других страницах тоже?

Буду признателен за любую подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

Тут не получится использовать тригер, потому что пока корзина совсем пустая кнопки обновления еще нет.
Как вариант это обновить фрагмент и вывести уже корзину с товарами после добавления товара в корзину. Не без багов конечно но на крайний случай можно использовать

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false');
add_filter('woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false');

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment($fragments)
{
 ob_start(); 
 ?>

    <div class="popap-cart">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]'); ?>
    </div>

<?php 
 $fragments['.popap-cart'] = ob_get_clean();

 return $fragments;
    
}
```